# How does one give priority to one word over others while matching?

Tags: regex, go

I have the following list.

```
ID    AllStatuses
1001  {failed|processing|success}
1002  {failed}
1003  {success|failed}
1004  {processing|success}
1005  {failed|processing}
```

My requirement is to display the most optimistic status alone. Like so

```
ID    Best Status
1001  success
1002  failed
1003  success
1004  success
1005  processing
```

Is there a way I can do this with one regex query rather than say check for each one in order and return where i'd have a worst case scenario of three regex checks for statuses with the most optimistic status in the end?

Comment: I believe regex is declarative and direct use of string patterns limits it's capabilities. You need simple `if/if else` conditions, not regex.

Comment: What are you using? python, php...?

Comment: @S.Jovan I'm using Go.

Comment: @zer00ne, I am able to handle it programmatically with conditions. I however would like to know if it could be done with regex too / if it's more efficient/ readable/ idiomatic.

Comment: No, this cannot be done with a regular expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Regex**: [`\{.*(success).*|\{.*(processing).*|\{.*(failed).*`](https://regex101.com/r/nCJyGe/2) Substitution: `$1$2$3`

[Details](http://golang.org/pkg/regexp/syntax):

- `.*` matches any character zero or more times
- `()` Capturing group
- `|` Or

**Go code**:

```
var re = regexp.MustCompile(`\{.*(success).*|\{.*(processing).*|\{.*(failed).*`)
s := re.ReplaceAllString(sample, `$1$2$3`)
```

Output:

```
ID    AllStatuses
1001  success
1002  failed
1003  success
1004  success
1005  processing
```

[Code demo](https://ideone.com/x54K8G)

Comment: But is alternation specified to behave the way you want it to? Referencing https://golang.org/pkg/regexp/syntax/ or the spec would be a good idea.

Comment: Regex generally prefers longest leftmost, so yes, order of alternatives matters and indicates an order of precedence.

Comment: Can be written easier: (\d+)\s+{.*(success|processing|failed).*}

Answer (score 1):

```
(\d+)\s+{.*(success|processing|failed).*}
```

Then take the match from 
group 1: ID 
group 2: status

Answer (score 0):

You can make it with **one regex**, but with additional checks of needed elements at the end in order you need this time.

It is not so short, but I am sure that this is more stable, especially if there will be some changes in algorithm.

Example in javascript, but I am sure, you can easily implement idea in your code

```js
var obResults = {};
var obStrings = {
  1001:  "{failed|processing|success}",
  1002:  "{failed}",
  1003:  "{success|failed}",
  1004:  "{processing|success}",
  1005:  "{failed|processing}",
};

for (var key in obStrings) {
  var stringToCheck = obStrings[key];
  var resultString = "";
  var arMathces = stringToCheck.match( /(failed|processing|success)/ig );
  
  if (arMathces.indexOf("success") != -1) {  
    resultString = "success";
  } else if (arMathces.indexOf("processing") != -1) {  
    resultString = "processing";
  } else if (arMathces.indexOf("failed") != -1) {  
    resultString = "failed";
  }
  
  obResults[key] = { result:resultString, check:stringToCheck };
}
console.log(obResults);
```